How to calculate the graph edge weights when doing arbitrage on Uniswap using Bellman-Ford?
I am trying to create an arbitrage bot on Uniswap by using graph data structure. On this graph tokens represent nodes and the exchange rate between tokens represent edge weights. By applying -log trick to these weights, we are able to benefit from the Bellman-Ford algorithm to find negative cycles on this graph which will indicate an arbitrage opportunity. Keep in mind that I don't care about fees for the sake of the question.
This is one of the main ways arbitrage is suggested to be done on the internet, and there are many articles explaining how to do this in 10 different ways. But there is one thing that I just can not find information on, which is, how do you calculate the exchange rate between tokens? Uniswap uses constant market-maker algorithm, which means that the exchange-rate is actually dependent on the input token amount, meaning its dynamic. So how can I accurately calculate edge weights?
